# How to link one tableView for My Courses to another tableView that stores Notes that are different for each course?

Tags: ios, swift

I have been working on a Note App for school. I have it mostly functional, but am sturggling with the structure and navigation between two tableViews. Currently my app allows users to create a Course name. It adds it to a table then seque to another tableView that stores notes. This is fully functional and stores the notes, but the second tableView is associated with every cell for the first tableView. How would I transition to the second tableView but populate a different set of notes?

**ViewController.swift**

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Note App
//
//  Created by user186587 on 12/2/20.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    var courseTextField: UITextField?
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    
    var data:[String] = []
    var fileURL:URL!

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        table.dataSource = self
        self.title = "Courses"
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        table.reloadData()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem!.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
        let baseURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        
        fileURL = baseURL.appendingPathComponent("notes.txt")
        
        
        load()
    }
    
    
    
    @IBAction func displayAlertAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add Course", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: courseTextField)
        
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [self]
            (paramAction:UIAlertAction!) in
            if let textFields = alertController.textFields{
                let theTextFields = textFields as [UITextField]
                let enteredText:String = theTextFields[0].text!
                data.insert(enteredText, at: 0)
                table.reloadData()
                
            }
        })
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        
        self.present(alertController, animated: true)
    }
    
    
    func courseTextField(textField: UITextField!){
        courseTextField = textField
        courseTextField?.placeholder = "Course Name"
    }
    
    func okHandler(alert: UIAlertAction!) {
        let viewController = AlertViewController()
        viewController.customInit(courseStr: (courseTextField?.text)!)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }
    
    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
        table.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        table.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        save()
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "notes", sender: nil)
        
    }
    
    func save() {
        //UserDefaults.standard.set(notes, forKey: "notes")
        let a = NSArray(array: data)
        do {
            try a.write(to: fileURL)
        } catch {
            print("error writing file")
        }
    }
    
    func load() {
        if let loadedData:[String] = NSArray(contentsOf:fileURL) as? [String] {
            data = loadedData
            table.reloadData()
        }
    }}
```

**NoteVC.swift**

```
//
//  NoteVC.swift
//  Note App
//
//  Created by user186587 on 12/6/20.
//

import UIKit

class NoteVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    var noteTextField: UITextField?
    


    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    var notes:[String] = ["Note 1"]
    var selectedRow:Int = -1
    var newRowText:String = ""
    var fileURL:URL!
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        table.dataSource = self
        table.delegate = self
        self.title = "Notes"
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        table.reloadData()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem!.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
        let baseURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        
        fileURL = baseURL.appendingPathComponent("notes.txt")
        
        load()
       
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if selectedRow == -1 {
            return
        }
        notes[selectedRow] = newRowText
        if newRowText == "" {
            notes.remove(at: selectedRow)
    
        }
        table.reloadData()
        save()
    }
    
    
    
    @IBAction func displayAlertAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add Note", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: noteTextField)
        
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [self]
            (paramAction:UIAlertAction!) in
            if let textFields = alertController.textFields{
                let theTextFields = textFields as [UITextField]
                let enteredText:String = theTextFields[0].text!
                notes.insert(enteredText, at: 0)
                table.reloadData()
                
            }
        })
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        
        self.present(alertController, animated: true)
        
    }
    
    
    

    func noteTextField(textField: UITextField!){
        noteTextField = textField
        noteTextField?.placeholder = "Note Name"
    }
    
    
    func okHandler(alert: UIAlertAction!) {
        let viewController = AlertViewController()
        viewController.customInit(courseStr: (noteTextField?.text)!)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return notes.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = notes[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }
    
    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
        table.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        notes.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        table.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        save()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detail", sender: nil)
        
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let detailView:DetailViewController = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
        selectedRow = table.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row
        detailView.masterView = self
        detailView.setText(t: notes[selectedRow])
    }
    
    func save() {
        //UserDefaults.standard.set(notes, forKey: "notes")
        let a = NSArray(array: notes)
        do {
            try a.write(to: fileURL)
        } catch {
            print("error writing file")
        }
    }
    
    func load() {
        if let loadedData:[String] = NSArray(contentsOf:fileURL) as? [String] {
            notes = loadedData
            table.reloadData()
        }
    }
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: U should abstract you question to a universal question，and simplify you demo code .

Comment: I would, but I'm not sure how to word it or what to specifically ask.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "populate a different set of notes"? The second view controller displays the notes associated with a particular cell from the first view controller, right?